# emitted value from an event can not be received

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-event-emitter

the distance-measurment-parameters.component is a child in site-map.component. The method hideWindowOverlay() in distance-measurment-parameters is invoked when a window is closed and it emits and event as shown below. the log
statement in the hideWindowOverlay() is displayed which indicates that the event is emitted.

in the component site-map.component, i listen or subscribe to the event 'evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed' as follows and as shown in the code below

```
(evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed)=onDistanceMeasurementWindowClosedEvtReceived($event)/>
```

The problem is, the mehtod onDistanceMeasurementWindowClosedEvtReceived() is never invoked, hence the event is not received.

please let me know how to subscribe to the event 'evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed' correctly and how to make the method 'onDistanceMeasurementWindowClosedEvtReceived' method is invoked

**in site-map.html**:

```
<clr-toggle-wrapper *ngIf="showMeasureDistance">
<input type="checkbox" clrCheckbox  (change)="toggleDistanceMeasurementOverlay()"  [(checked)]="showMeasureDistanceOverlay"
(evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed)=onDistanceMeasurementWindowClosedEvtReceived($event)/>
<label >
    {{ "SITE.MEASURE_DISTANCE" | translate }} 
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_MEASURE_DISTANCE')">
        <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
    </button>

</label>
</clr-toggle-wrapper>
```

**distance-measurment-parameters.component**:

```
//declaration of the event emitter
@Output("evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed")
evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed: EventEmitter<boolean> = new 
EventEmitter<boolean>();

hideWindowOverlay() {
//throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
this.showWindow = false;
this.evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed.emit(true);
console.log("hideWindowOverlay: emits event this.evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed.emit(true)");//log here are displayed
}
```

**in site-map.component**:

```
onDistanceMeasurementWindowClosedEvtReceived(event: boolean){
    this.toggleDistanceMeasurementOverlay();  
    console.log("onDistanceMeasurementWindowClosedEvtReceived: ");//log are not displayed

}
```

Comment: has you declare `evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed=new EventEmitter<bool>();`? -see that you neeed equal to new EventEmitter-

Comment: Shouldnt you have double quotes here? `(evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed)=onDistanceMeasurementWindowClosedEvtReceived($event)/>` or does it compiles anyway?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're trying to listen to a evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed event from an *input* element, but *input* hasn't such event emitter. Try to call onDistanceMeasurementWindowClosedEvtReceived method on some of the built-in input events - onchange e.g.

Or use [(ngModel)] like this

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value"
        (ngModelChange)="onDistanceMeasurementWindowClosedEvtReceived($event)"
      />
```

Comment: please let me know why do you think it should be an input not output?also i tried the answer you posted but received the same results

Comment: I was talking about <input/> html element which hasn't evtEmitterOnDistanceMeasurementWindowClosed output/event emitter. To use [(ngModel)] you have to import FormsModule